# drupal what is vid in node_revision

Tags: database, drupal, drupal-6

am exploring drupal 6.15 ,

am going to do the DB migration ,plain db to drupal db ,

what is vid field in node_revision table in drupal cms ,

i thing vid not an vocabulary id, but plz clear it

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the migrate module for migration from a non-Drupal database. Drupal's database structure is incredibly complicated. It's much more reliable to add content with code (as migrate does) rather than trying to write directly to the database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

vid is the version id the id of the revision.

The vid is the serial and primary key in the node_revision table. If you haven't made any revisions the nid and vid will always be equal. But once you start making revisions, the vid and nid  will be of by the number of revisions made.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I figured it out from the database structure as well. Do you know exactly how the nid and vid are calculated when I update a node?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the revisions table is enabled by default, i.e. In d8 the node table is like:

nid int(10) unsigned Auto Increment 
vid int(10) unsigned NULL
type    varchar(32) The ID of the target entity.
uuid    varchar(128)
langcode    varchar(12)

with the following being indexes:

PRIMARY nid
UNIQUE  uuid
UNIQUE  vid
INDEX   type

The node revisions looks a little like this:

nid int(10) unsigned
vid int(10) unsigned Auto Increment 
langcode    varchar(12) 
revision_timestamp  int(11) NULL
revision_uid    int(10) unsigned NULL   The ID of the target entity.
revision_log    longtext NULL
revision_default    tinyint(4) NULL

with the following being indexes:

PRIMARY vid
INDEX   nid
INDEX   langcode
INDEX   revision_uid

This is enabled irrespective of whether node revisions is actually enabled or not. So to enable this feature, i.e. have revision-able content my guess is you simply need to enable from the respective content type and configure by selecting the checkbox option under:

/admin/structure/types/manage/

As mentioned previously the table structure in drupal is complicated, but is worth trying to understand, so to complete the explanation on this the header for the node is stored in 'node_field_data':

nid int(10) unsigned
vid int(10) unsigned
type    varchar(32) The ID of the target entity.
langcode    varchar(12) 
title   varchar(255)
status  tinyint(4)
created int(11) 
changed int(11) 
promote tinyint(4)
sticky  tinyint(4)
revision_translation_affected   tinyint(4) NULL 
default_langcode    tinyint(4)
uid int(10) unsigned    The ID of the target entity.

and has the following indexes

PRIMARY nid, langcode
INDEX   nid, default_langcode, langcode
INDEX   vid
INDEX   type
INDEX   created
INDEX   changed
INDEX   promote, status, sticky, created
INDEX   status, type, nid
INDEX   title(191), type(4)
INDEX   uid

Interestingly this contains the 'title' field, as well as the nid, vid and type of node.

There is also the node_field_revision table.

nid int(10) unsigned
vid int(10) unsigned
langcode    varchar(12) 
title   varchar(255) NULL
status  tinyint(4)
created int(11) NULL
changed int(11) NULL
promote tinyint(4) NULL 
sticky  tinyint(4) NULL 
revision_translation_affected   tinyint(4) NULL 
default_langcode    tinyint(4)
uid int(10) unsigned    The ID of the target entity.

Indexes

PRIMARY vid, langcode
INDEX   nid, default_langcode, langcode
INDEX   uid

Unless the revisions feature is enabled the vid and nid will be the same.

And then for each additional field attached to the content type, e.g. node__body there is:

bundle  varchar(128) [] The field instance bundle to which this row belongs, used when deleting a field instance
deleted tinyint(4) [0]  A boolean indicating whether this data item has been deleted
entity_id   int(10) unsigned    The entity id this data is attached to
revision_id int(10) unsigned    The entity revision id this data is attached to
langcode    varchar(32) []  The language code for this data item.
delta   int(10) unsigned    The sequence number for this data item, used for multi-value fields
body_value  longtext
body_summary    longtext NULL
body_format varchar(255) NULL

Indexes

PRIMARY entity_id, deleted, delta, langcode
INDEX   bundle
INDEX   revision_id
INDEX   body_format

Which in turn also has its own revision table:

bundle  varchar(128) [] The field instance bundle to which this row belongs, used when deleting a field instance
deleted tinyint(4) [0]  A boolean indicating whether this data item has been deleted
entity_id   int(10) unsigned    The entity id this data is attached to
revision_id int(10) unsigned    The entity revision id this data is attached to
langcode    varchar(32) []  The language code for this data item.
delta   int(10) unsigned    The sequence number for this data item, used for multi-value fields
body_value  longtext
body_summary    longtext NULL
body_format varchar(255) NULL

Indexes

PRIMARY entity_id, revision_id, deleted, delta, langcode
INDEX   bundle
INDEX   revision_id
INDEX   body_format

So for example if I have a field called field_feed_item_description attached to my node entity then I am also likely to have something like:

node__field_feed_item_description

bundle  varchar(128) [] The field instance bundle to which this row belongs, used when deleting a field instance
deleted tinyint(4) [0]  A boolean indicating whether this data item has been deleted
entity_id   int(10) unsigned    The entity id this data is attached to
revision_id int(10) unsigned    The entity revision id this data is attached to
langcode    varchar(32) []  The language code for this data item.
delta   int(10) unsigned    The sequence number for this data item, used for multi-value fields
field_feed_item_description_value   longtext
field_feed_item_description_summary longtext NULL
field_feed_item_description_format  varchar(255) NULL

indexes

PRIMARY entity_id, deleted, delta, langcode
INDEX   bundle
INDEX   revision_id
INDEX   field_feed_item_description_format

and

node_revision__field_feed_item_description

bundle  varchar(128) [] The field instance bundle to which this row belongs, used when deleting a field instance
deleted tinyint(4) [0]  A boolean indicating whether this data item has been deleted
entity_id   int(10) unsigned    The entity id this data is attached to
revision_id int(10) unsigned    The entity revision id this data is attached to
langcode    varchar(32) []  The language code for this data item.
delta   int(10) unsigned    The sequence number for this data item, used for multi-value fields
field_feed_item_description_value   longtext
field_feed_item_description_summary longtext NULL
field_feed_item_description_format  varchar(255) NULL

Indexes

PRIMARY entity_id, revision_id, deleted, delta, langcode
INDEX   bundle
INDEX   revision_id
INDEX   field_feed_item_description_format

Actually it looks like the db schema is documented here. Not sure what the difference is between 6 and 7 but my feeling is they will be similar.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1785994